# Constructing a markov chain and giving its transition probabilities

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the question and I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction. This is how I have the transition probability matrix:

$$s+1<j<S$$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
& j & s+1 & S \\
\hline j & 0 & 0 & z_{1}+z_{2} \\
\hline s+1 & 0 & 0 & z_{4} \\
\hline S & z_{6} & z_{3}+z_{7} & z_{5}
\end{array}

I will highly appreciate any guidance or hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

The stock level $\ \ell\ $ at the beginning of any period is some integer between $\ s+1\ $ and $\ S\ $. This will be the state of your Markov chain, which therefore has $\ S-s\ $ states, $\ \ell\in\{s+1, s+2,\dots, S\}\ $.  If the demand during the period is $\ z\ $ and $\ \ell-z\ge s+1\ $, then the state at the beginning of the next period—that is, the stock level then—will be $\ \ell-z\ $.  So what's the probability of that happening, given the value of $\ \ell\ $?

On the other hand, if $\ \ell-z\le s\ $, the stock   gets replenished and its level at the start of the  next period will be $\ S\ $. Given the value of $\ \ell\ $, what's the probability of that happening?

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting and helping! I am still quite confused maybe because im working with arbitrary numbers at the same time. Anyway, I gave it a shot again this time making $s = 2$ and $S = 5$. Hence I will have 3 states. If I make $\ell = 4$, then $4-z \geq 3$  will occur when the demand is ${Z_1} = 1, {Z_5} = 1$ and ${Z_4} = 1$ which has the probability of $\frac{3}{7}$. Similarly, $4-z \leq 2$ when the demand is ${Z_2}, {Z_3}, {Z_6}, {Z_7} $ which has the probability of $\frac{4}{7}$. Am I right? But then I am confused about the probability for 3 -> 4 ?

Comment: I am also somewhat confused how can I calculate the probability if $/ell$ , $s$ and $S$ are arbitrary? Wont the probabilities be different depending on the values of $s$ and $S$?